# Nested `for()` loops makes R frozen

Tags: r, for-loop

I am having a huge trouble with R when I need to run double `for()` loops. The problem I need to solve is very simple: I have two data frames, one is`d1_valid`, and the other is `stops`. For every pairs of the same `lat` and `lon` in `d1_valid` and `stops` (column `X5` and `X6`), if they are equal, the corresponding element in column `ZONE` of `d1_valid` would be filled with the element in column `X8` from `stops`. The code is following:

```
   for (i in seq_len(length(d1_valid$lat))){
    for(k in (2:length(stops$X5))){
      if(d1_valid$lat[i] == as.numeric(stops$X5[k]) && d1_valid$lon[i] == as.numeric(stops$X6[k])){
        d1_validd$ZONE[i] <- stops$X8[k]
      } 
    }
}
```

With this two simple `for()` loops, I thought R would take less than 10 minutes to run (even though the dataset is pretty large). However, it took **more than 30 minutes**, and absolutely nothing was produced. The reason is because I know for sure, theoretically, every element in the `ZONE` column should not be `NA` but should be matched to one of the elements in column `X8` of `stops`.

Attached is the picture showing R just keep buffering like this (sometime, I let R run for 8 hours, and still, no error message or output came out!) 
[image]
[image]

[Two Data Frames included in file .Rdata](https://drive.google.com/open?id=19bJT6UvWV4lkDFi4Nbi-vKWGcshntUQz)

**My question:** Could someone please give this code a try, with the dataset uploaded above? I keep having this problem over and over, and I don't understand why a powerful software specializing in data analysis like R fails to do such a simple **nested** `for()` loops.

Comment: How many rows are in each of your data frames? Seems like you probably be doing a join/merge here rather than a double for loop.

Comment: Looping over your observations may not be the ideal solution if the number of rows are very large. You are effecting looking for a left join here if I am not mistaken? Try `dplyr::left_join(x = d1_valid, y = stops %>% select(X5, X6, X8),
by = c("lat" = "X5", "long" = "X6"))`. X8 would be appended to your d1_valid dataset.

Comment: You need to make your sample data smaller. I don't think anyone wants to download a 300MB file

Comment: Your `lat` and `lon` columns are `numeric`, whereas `X5` and `X6` are `character` columns. I guess that's the reason for `NA` values everywhere. Using `merge` R gave up saying it can't allocate a vector of size 35 MB. Using `left_join` R gave up saying it can't allocate a vector of size 64 MB. Seems I can't help with the whole dataset. But when I fired it up with a small subset (`head(d1_valid,10000)`), seems good to use `merge`/`left_join`.

Comment: @Vlo: not sure why my previous comment was deleted. I tried your suggested code, but I got the error: `Error in left_join_impl(x, y, by$x, by$y, suffix$x, suffix$y, check_na_matches(na_matches)) : 
  Can't join on 'X5' x 'lat' because of incompatible types (character / numeric).` 

I changed it to:
`stops$X5 <- as.numeric(stops$X5)
stops$X6 <- as.numeric(stops$X6)
d1_n <- dplyr::left_join(x = d1_valid, y = stops %>% select(X5, X6), by = c("lat" = "X5", "lon" = "X6")).` 
But I still got the same result as in the OP (https://drive.google.com/open?id=1WU8r5p6WUT_ORZe6BKao0FI8e8RZllI5).

Comment: The `NA` is not the fault. It is the initial value for every elements under the column `X8`.

Comment: Nevertheless, considering you want a `merge`/`join` your data types should be the same for by variables. And, considering you only have the first row as a character (by fault of `read.table`), use `tail(stops, - 1)` and then change the data types to numeric

Comment: @Vlo: do you know why, after  using what you suggested, the resulting dataset's size is only half of the original dataset? Assuming that some pairs of `lat-lon` might be repeated in the original dataset, does it mean left_join only acts on *unique* pair of lat-lon??

Comment: @samkart: both of those choices did NOT work, as they add more elements into the left_joint table. I am so disappointed by the result;p Could you actually get your hand dirty to help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although R is designed for data analysis, new users are advised to review the fundamentals of the language before diving in and applying language constructs that are known to have poor performance characteristics. One such feature is doing iterative Boolean tests using `if(.){action}` inside nested for-loops. Using vectorized comparisons will be faster if feasible.

In your case, however, I believe designing such efforts might be  premature anyway, since you do not have data structures that lend themselves well to the tests you are conducting:

```
str(d1_valid)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   4505026 obs. of  12 variables:
 $ lat         : num  41.7 42 41.7 41.7 42 ...
 $ lon         : num  -87.6 -87.7 -87.6 -87.6 -87.9 ...
 $ START_TIME  : chr  "2016-03-01 00:03:33" "2016-03-01 00:06:31" "2016-03-01 00:12:13" "2016-03-01 00:15:29" ...
 $ DIRECTION   : chr  "North" "East" "South" "South" ...
 $ Hour        : chr  "0000" "0000" "0000" "0000" ...
 $ TRIP_TYPE   : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
 $ STOP        : chr  "Route_ID 712 not defined" "Route_ID 685 not defined" "Route_ID 711 not defined" "Route_ID 711 not defined" ...
 $ COST        : chr  "0" "0" "0" "0" ...
 $ Count       : chr  "1" "1" "1" "1" ...
 $ ROUTE_Number: chr  "353" "290" "352" "352" ...
 $ Trans_status: chr  "No Payment" "No Payment" "No Payment" "No Payment" ...
 $ ZONE        : chr  "502" NA NA NA ...
> str(stops)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   23546 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ X3: chr  "stop_name" "4201 Winfield/International" "Washington/School" "Washington/School" ...
 $ X5: chr  "stop_lat" "41.8090901" "41.7775918" "41.7774673" ...
 $ X6: chr  "stop_lon" "-88.1660011" "-88.1473181" "-88.147536" ...
 $ X8: chr  "zone" "1306" "1384" "1318" ...
```

Your tests are:

```
 d1_valid$lat[i] == as.numeric(stops$X5[k])
 d1_valid$lon[i] == as.numeric(stops$X6[k])
```

I think you made a data error in not using header=TRUE when doing a `read.table`, because there is only a single non-numeric value in each of those columns (and a character value with a probable column name appears first in the other two `stops`-columns as well).:

```
> table( stops$X5[ is.na( as.numeric(stops$X5) )])

stop_lat 
       1 
Warning message:
In table(stops$X5[is.na(as.numeric(stops$X5))]) :
  NAs introduced by coercion
> table( stops$X6[ is.na( as.numeric(stops$X6) )])

stop_lon 
       1 
Warning message:
In table(stops$X6[is.na(as.numeric(stops$X6))]) :
  NAs introduced by coercion
```

If you had offered str(.) on the relevant data objects, there would have been no need to download the file. I also fail to see where you defined a `d1_validd` object to hold results of the assignment in the inner loop and I suspect that was a typo.

Comment: Great point! Thank you so much for your help. I should have mentioned: `d1_valid` <---- `d1[d1$Trans_status != "Transaction created to store repriced trip data",]`. The reason I left out `header=TRUE` is because the `.dat` files do not have any column headers. They are all strings separated by `delim="|"`. Plus, I am used to deal with `data.frame` rather than `table` in R, due to certain functions not being applicable to `table` but to `data.frame` -object only.

Comment: When I saw that the lat and lon were 'character' I wondered if there were a lot of comments or missing value indicators. There still could be I suppose if the data gathers used 999 or such.

Comment: I eliminated all of those cases, so the data in `.Rdata` is very clean, no worries:)